# Interesting bound over a series for any $c \neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, inequality

How can I show that for any $c \neq 0$,

$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2} 1 \{ |c| \le i \} \le \frac{1+|c|}{c^2}$ ?

I was trying to bound this summation by an integral of $\frac{1}{x^2}$ over the set $\{ x \ge |c| \}$ but that is not giving me the desired RHS.

Is there a way to approach this?

Comment: Can you explain the notation $1\{ |c|\le i\}$?

Comment: @ArcticChar my guess is an indicator function, as in $\mathbf{1}_{A}=\chi_A(x)$

Comment: Then probably one should have $|1_{\{ |c|\le i\}}\ |$ @Integrand